# onSnapshot, forEach, and get() synchronously on Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase's `.onSnapshot` to grab the ID of the users currently online, and store each ID to an array. I successfully deployed `.onSnapshot` to get the ID of the online users, but I return an empty array at the end

```
var learning_language;
db.collection(ll_profile).doc(user_uid).get().then(function(doc) {
  learning_language = doc.data().learning_language;
})

db.collection(ns_status).where("state", "==", "online").onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
  var ns_match = [ ];
  snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
    db.collection("ns_profile").doc(userSnapshot.id).get().then(function(doc) {
      spoken_language = doc.data().spoken_language;
      if (learning_language == spoken_language) {
        ns_match.push(userSnapshot.id);
        console.log(ns_match);
      }
    })
  })
  return (ns_match);
```

What I am trying to do is to first define the `learning_language` retrieved from the collection `ll_profile` with the current user's ID named `user_uid.`

Then .onSnapshot listens to another group of users' online state (which automatically updates if an user is online or offline) inside `ns_status` collection. After, the returned online user from `.onSnapshot` is checked if the `spoken_language` field inside their document (named with their corresponding uid) matches with `learning_language` defined earlier. If it matches, then store the uid into the array of `ns_match.`

The values inside `ns_match` are correct. I think `.get()` executes asynchronously. That is why `ns_match` is returned empty.

How should I return `ns_match` at the end with all the values stored properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use promise or callbacks. No need to make this call asynchronous\

Answer (score 1):

```
function getMatches() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    db.collection(ll_profile).doc(user_uid).get()
      .then(function(doc) {
        var learning_language = doc.data().learning_language;
        db.collection(ns_status)
          .where("state", "==", "online")
          .onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
            var ns_match = [];
            snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
              db.collection("ns_profile")
                .doc(userSnapshot.id)
                .get()
                .then(function(doc) {
                  spoken_language = doc.data().spoken_language;
                  if (learning_language == spoken_language) {
                    ns_match.push(userSnapshot.id);
                    console.log(ns_match);
                  }
                });
            });
            resolve(ns_match);
          });
      });
  });
}


getMatches().then(ns_matches => console.log(ns_matches));
```

Comment: Hi Tanmay, tried exactly what you provided, it still returns the resolve as an empty array, then stores the values inside  after.

Answer (score 0):

wrapping in a promise is the correct move. However, remember that snapshot returns metadata about your result. Particularly, `snapshot.size`. One can use that value to count records, inside the `foreach` method, or compare the destination array length with the snapshot.size value